# Efficient Search for reverse element in List of Lists

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning, searching

I have a big list `AllCycles` with contains lists of non-repeating integers (and the first element is always the smallest). I want a function `findReversePairs` to find all pairs of `Reverse` lists.

For example:

```
AllCycles={{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 10, 2, 5}, {1, 4, 3, 2}, {1, 5, 2, 10}}
findReversePairs[AllCycles] (* {{{1, 2, 3, 4},1,3}, {{1, 10, 2, 5},2,4} *)
```

where the output is a list of all such pairs, with `{list, index1, index2}`, where `index1` and `index2` is the index of the first and second item of the pair.

This can be simply done with two for-loops, but it is very slow therefore I am searching for a faster solution. My code is here:

```
(*Function for rearranging list such that smallest element is always the first element*)
StartListAtSmallest[llist_] := (
   SLASpos = Position[llist, Min[llist]][[1, 1]];
   SLASrl = Flatten[{llist[[SLASpos ;;]], llist[[1 ;; SLASpos]]}][[1 ;; -2]];
   Return[SLASrl];
   );

findReversePairs[list_] := (
  CurrTime = AbsoluteTime[];
  AllReverse = {};
  For[index1 = 1, index1 <= Length[list] - 1, index1++,
   RevCycle = StartListAtSmallest[Reverse[list[[index1]]]];
   For[index2 = index1 + 1, index2 <= Length[list], index2++,
    If[RevCycle == list[[index2]],
      AppendTo[AllReverse, {list[[index1]], index1, index2}];
      ];
    ];
   ];
  Return[AllReverse];
  )



SeedRandom[42]
(*Make a list with 2500 entries*)
AllCycles = {};
For[ii = 1, ii <= 2500, ii++,
  AppendTo[AllCycles, StartListAtSmallest[RandomSample[Range[13], 5]]];
  ];


ListReverse = findReversePairs[AllCycles];

Length[ListReverse] (*95 entries*)
Print[AbsoluteTime[] - CurrTime]; (*6.1841130 seconds*)
```

My code need roughly 6.2 seconds, and it scales quadratically with the number of list items, which is very unfortunate.

> Do you know of a faster, more efficient solution?

Comment: `GatherBy[AllCycles , Sort[Rest@#] &]` ... then organize?

Comment: @kglr Thank you for your answer. I was playing with `GatherBy` in a similar fashion as searching for Duplicates, but was not successful. Unfortunately, your solution gives a different result as my function: `Length[GatherBy[AllCycles, Sort[Rest@#] &]] (* 477 *)`, instead it should be 95 entries. And I dont really understand what the idea of the suolution is -- could you please explain a few bits? Thank you!!

Comment: `GatherBy[AllCycles , Sort[Rest@#] &]`  allows the first entries of `c1` and `c2`  to be different and the other entries can be in any order as long as they have common elements. Perhaps a version with `Gather` would work.

Comment: it would be great if you would find a solution -- i spend some hours playing with `GatherBy` but not successfully until now. Would really like to know how to exploit the syntax of these fancy functions to get that work.

Comment: NicoDean,  all entries in your `ListReverse` on the timing experiment have length `2`. However, for example, the three entries  {{2, 13, 4, 5, 7}, {2, 7, 5, 4, 13}, {2, 7, 5, 4, 13}}` (these are the entries in  `AllCycles[[{56, 2139, 2140}]]` ) satisfy your condition and the correct result should include `{{2, 13, 4, 5, 7}, 56, 2139, 2140}`,  don't you think?

Comment: @kgle I am not sure whether I understand your question. For later evaluation, i need the items to contain the array and the two indices. The correct result items you mention are actually in the list as `ListReverse[[{3, 4}]]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ended up with this

```
ListReverse === 
    With[{res = DeleteDuplicates[Sort /@ Catenate[With[{pos = PositionIndex[AllCycles]},
     With[{invP = Lookup[pos, RotateRight[Reverse[Keys[pos], 2], {0, 1}], 0]},
      MapThread[Thread@*List, {Values[pos][[#, 1]], invP[[#]]} &[
       Catenate[Position[invP, Except[0], {1}, Heads -> False]]]]]]]]},
         Join[Transpose[{AllCycles[[res[[All, 1]]]]}], res, 2]]
```

> True

The first four lines creates `ListReverse[[All, {2, 3}]]` (which i call `res`), and the last line adds the cycles to make it `ListReverse`.

Comment: Wow. 0.01seconds. :-o Thank you so much. Increadible speedup of more than a factor of 500! The code looks quite involved. Could you maybe give a big-picture explanation of it? Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

```
ClearAll[indicesF, gatheredF, pairsF]
gatheredF[cycs_] := GatherBy[Range @ Length @ cycs, Sort[cycs[[#]]] &]/. {_} :> Sequence[]

indicesF[cycs_] := Join @@ (Pick[#, Rest[cycs[[#[[1]]]]] == 
     Reverse[Rest@cycs[[#[[2]]]]] & /@ #] & /@ (Subsets[#, {2}] & /@ gatheredF[cycs]))

pairsF[cycs_] := {cycs[[#]][[1]], ## & @@ #} & /@ indicesF[cycs]
```

**Examples:**

```
example1 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 10, 2, 5}, {1, 4, 3, 2}, {1, 5, 2, 10}};
pairsF[example1]
```

> {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, 1, 3}, {{1, 10, 2, 5}, 2, 4}}

```
example2 = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 10, 2, 5}, {1, 4, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 3,  2},
 {1, 5, 2, 10}, {3, 6, 7, 8, 9}};
pairsF[example2]
```

> {{{1, 2, 3, 4}, 1, 3}, {{1, 2, 3, 4}, 1, 4}, {{1, 10, 2, 5}, 2, 5}}

**Timings:**

Using the test data `AllCycles`in OP

```
(ListReverse = findReversePairs[AllCycles]) // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {4.73499, 95}

```
(result = pairsF[AllCycles]) // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.020525, 95}

```
Sort @ ListReverse == Sort @ result
```

> True

Coolwater's method is uncomparably faster:

```
 (result2 = coolwater[AllCycles]) // Length // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.006522, 95}

Comment: For some reason, your solution has only `91` entries (instead of 95), and it takes 9.5seconds (~30% longer than my original one). Or maybe this is a mistake on my side?

Comment: @NicoDean, took a while but i finally got the `95`:)

Comment: GatherBy is the right idea, but implement it differently: base it on the *signatures* of the sublists. A quick-n-dirty is much faster than alternative answer...

Comment: @ciao,   _signatures_ doesn't ring a bell. Do you mind posting an answer    or a reference?

Comment: @kglr - mobile for rest of day... but e.g. for sublist *s*, `Sort[{s,Reverse[RotateLeft[s]]}]` uniquely identifies matching lists. Transposing those with the whole list, then gathering on signature, with appropriate garnishing, will be quite quick...

Comment: wonderful; had no idea it would be that simple/elegant. Thank you @ciao.